# Logging all Bro streams

Tags: bro

I want to log all the streams the Bro has to offer. I did the following for one stream but I am not getting the desired answer.

```bro
redef LogAscii::use_json=T;
redef LogAscii::json_timestamps = JSON::TS_ISO8601;

export
{
    # Append the value LOG to the Log::ID enumerable.
    redef enum Log::ID += { LOG };
}

event bro_init()
{
    #Create the logging stream
    Log::create_stream(LOG, [$columns=IRC::Info, $path="irc"]);
    Log::write(LOG, IRC::Info) ; 
}
```

Can I get any help with this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you feeding traffic into Bro?  Bro will only creates log files when it generates a log line which would go into that log.

Your script doesn't execute either, you are try to pass a type (IRC::Info) into a field that expects a value of that type.

You also don't need to call `Log::create_stream`, it is part of the base IRC support which is loaded by default.

Comment: Thanks Seth for the reply. My problem was that Bro wasn't generating the logs for the frameworks because the I didn't have any data that would lead all those scripts to run. Got that after some research into how Bro was written.